# Schema design for review with rating and optional items

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am by no means a SQL/DB expert. Currently working on an evaluation/rating app and having doubts with the design.

The context is as follows: There are a number of organisations in the system that could deliver services. Every organisation can have multiple services and services can be delivered by multiple orgnisations. Users are able to evaluate/rate the organisations. Optionally, with every evaluation, they can also specify whether or not a service is present.

This is what I am thinking about in terms of design (I cannot post images yet):[DB Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXfwS.png)

- Many to many relationship between Organisations and Services
- Many to many relationship between Evaluations and Services
- One to many relationship between Organisations and Evaluations

My questions would be whether this is a good approach to follow? Or should the evaluation/rating be threated separately from the actual setting of the services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. You can have the Organisations and the Services table, together with the linking table OrganisationServices.

And for the evaluation part, you can have another table Evaluations(id, userId, organisationId, serviceId, score), as I think you really want to rate the specific service of an organisation (really big organisations cand have services in multiple domains of activity). Be careful to have a unique constraint for user, organisation and service.

This way, if you want to have an overall score for an organisation, you can just do a simple query to do a mean of the scores for all the services of that organisation.

Hope this helped you in some way.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Just one more question though. The evaluation of the services is not so much like rating the service itself but more like stating whether the service is presented (Similar as you have TripAdvisor or something asking you: "Is this resturant good for vegetarians?". Would you then still have the one table for evaluations?

Comment: So it would be something like: "did you enjoy our services?" yes/no?

Comment: But if you want to have some sort of opinion of the service, just change the name of the column from score to opinion, and there you can store the user's opinion

Comment: Yes, something like that. But then for each of the services that the organisation delivers. But indeed something like yes/no questions. This is optional though, so a user is not required to enter these while doing the evaluation. Score might indeed be badly chosen name. It was intended to have a 0/1 value for yes/no.

Comment: And are the questions predetermined?

Comment: They are questions asking about the services (from the services table).

Comment: ok. So, if each service can have a set of questions, you can have another table Questions(id, serviceId, question) and then the Evaluations table changes to: (id, userId, organisationId, serviceId, questionId, answer), and answer could be a boolean(for yes/no) or a string(for more complex answers), whichever you like.